# How to let babel just transform import to require without adding additional code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm using babel to transform Node.js code from es6 to es5, the thing is Node.js naturally supports cmd styled require and class, it doesn't need tons of additional code like this below

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _createClass = function() {
  function defineProperties(target, props) {
    for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
      var descriptor = props[i];
      descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false;
      descriptor.configurable = true;
      if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true;
      Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor);
    }
  }
  return function(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
    if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
    if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);
    return Constructor;
  };
}();
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I was going to say 'transform import to require'.

Comment: I never used that transformation for node code (require looks fine enough to me) but you should be able to use [babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify).

Comment: What's your current babel config `.babelrc`? You can just use `{plugins:['transform-es2015-modules-commonjs']}`. But there will still be a little extra code than just converting one line import statement to one line require statement because import syntax requires some extra handling of default exports